# Using dot (.) as delimiter to specify group in chown

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, chown

I've always done:

```
chown nimmylebby:admins file
```

I see that this also works:

```
chown nimmylebby.admins file
```

Might seem like a silly question but I'm genuinely curious on how the latter works. It isn't documented in my chown's manpage (GNU coreutils 8.4, 10/10). Is this perhaps a Bash interpretation? Or a deprecated format for the argument?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [chown(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html) manpage on Mac OS X version 10.9:

> COMPATIBILITY
>
> Previous versions of the chown utility used the dot (``.'') character to
>   distinguish the group name. This has been changed to be a colon (``:'')
>   character, so that user and group names may contain the dot character.

Answer (score 25):

From [`info coreutils 'chown invocation'`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html) for GNU `coreutils`:

> Some older scripts may still use '.' in place of the ':' separator.
>   POSIX 1003.1-2001 (see [Standards conformance](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Standards-conformance.html)) does not require
>   support for that, but for backward compatibility GNU `chown` supports
>   '.' so long as no ambiguity results.  New scripts should avoid the use
>   of '.' because it is not portable, and because it has undesirable
>   results if the entire *owner*'.'*group* happens to identify a user whose
>   name contains '.'.